# How to find the similarity percentage of two string using mongoDb

Tags: mongodb

My Data Set

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e39608c0aba3a775c55cf22"),
    "title" : "Ashford Hospitality Prime Inc. (AHP) Shares Obtained by Acrospire Investment Management LLC - BangaloreWeekly",
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e39608c0aba3a775c55cf23"),
    "title" : "The current 14-day ATR for Intelli PharmaCeutics International Inc",
}
```

My pattern to be checked is **Ashford Hospitality Prime Inc** on the above data set. I want to find the similarity percentage of the pattern on my data set.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a [text index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/#text-indexes) on the title field, you can use the [$text](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text) operator to compare the search string, and use projection to include the [text score](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/#text-score) in the output.

Comment: But score does not give the percentage, it only gives the relevance.We cannot search for **stop and stemming words** using **text index**.

Comment: If you select language "none" there will be no stemming or stop word removal.  "Similarity Percentage" could mean lots of things, if you divide the score by a reasonable maximum that will give you a percentage